# Перетащить картинку со своего приложения на сайт с функцией Drag-and-drop

Tags: python, pyqt5, drag-n-drop, qlabel, веб-сайт

Есть приложение, в котором отображается картинка через `QLabel` и `QPixmap`.

Есть сайт, на который можно загрузить фотографию при помощи `Drag and Drop`.

Как я могу сделать так, чтобы я мог со своего приложения перетащить картинку на сайт?

Может картинки нужно по другому отображать ?

Comment: Вы пишите, что есть приложение в котором отображается картинка через QLabel и QPixmap - опубликуйте его. Если сайт, о котором вы пишите - публичный, дайте ссылку на него. И опишите лучше, что именно у вас не получается, захватить картину для перетаскивания или вы получаете какую-то ошибку или что?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я написал для вас приложение, в котором отображается картинка через `QLabel` и `QPixmap`.

Нашел сайт `https://ru.stackoverflow.com`, 
на который можно загрузить изображение при помощи `Drag and Drop`,
в котором я пишу ответ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Я обозначил строки в приложении, которые делают то что вы хотите:

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5.Qt import * 


class DraggableLabelImage(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, path, parent):            
        super(DraggableLabelImage, self).__init__(parent)

        self.path = path
        self.setPixmap(QPixmap(self.path).scaled(150, 150))          # 3

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drag_start_position = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not (event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton):
            return
        if (event.pos() - self.drag_start_position).manhattanLength() < QApplication.startDragDistance():
            return

        # Класс QDrag обеспечивает поддержку перетаскивания данных на основе MIME-based 
        drag = QDrag(self)                                           # 4

        # Класс QMimeData предоставляет контейнер для данных, 
        # в котором записывается информация о его типе MIME. 
        mimedata = QMimeData()                                       # 5

        # QMimeData::setUrls(const QList<QUrl> &urls)
        # Устанавливает URL-адреса, хранящиеся в объекте данных MIME, на те, 
        # которые указаны в URL-адресах.
        # URL-адреса соответствуют MIME-типу text/uri-list.
        # Начиная с Qt 5.0, setUrls также экспортирует URL-адреса в виде простого текста ...
        mimedata.setUrls([QUrl.fromLocalFile(self.path)])            # 6

        drag.setMimeData(mimedata)
        pixmap = QPixmap(self.size())
        painter = QPainter(pixmap)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self.grab())
        painter.end()
        drag.setPixmap(pixmap)
        drag.setHotSpot(event.pos())
        drag.exec_(Qt.CopyAction | Qt.MoveAction)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        path = "D:/_Qt/img/head.jpg"                                 # 1

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.labelImage = DraggableLabelImage(path, self)            # 2

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.labelImage, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**head.jpg**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]